# SQL Server 2012 procedure wrong calculation?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2012, and I'm facing a weird problem.

Here is my partial procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[abc1]
    @myDate date
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @avgMonth int;
    set @avgMonth = 12 - month(@myDate) + 1;

    update costtable 
    set balance = 1 / @avgMonth
END
```

When I enter the parameter `@myDate='2015-1-1'`, `@avgmonth` should be 12, and balance should be 1/12, but the results is 0. And I have tried bigger number or power function, still get wrong results.

The datatype of balance column numeric(18,8).

What should I do?

By the way, what's the terminology for " 1/x " in english?

Thanks.

Comment: This is because you are doing division on an integer datatype. Change your code to be 1.0/@avgMonth and it will return the values you are expecting.

Comment: @Sean why is this a comment not an answer?

Comment: @SeanLange took the words right out of my mouth. 1.0 will help the complier realise you're looking for a float rather than an int

Comment: @ChristianBarron to be precise it will use a numeric/decimal as a precise datatype, not a float which is an approximate type. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Integer arithmetic is the cause. 1/12 is equals to 0 since 1 and 12 are both integer

Try this.

```
alter  PROCEDURE [dbo].[abc1]
@myDate date
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @avgMonth int;
set @avgMonth=12-month(@myDate)+1;
update costtable set balance=1.0/@avgMonth
END
```

Note that I replaced 1 with 1.0, so @avbMoth will be converted